# Grant Read access to all notebooks in Databricks Workspace for a user/group

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to grant access to a user to all notebooks within the workspace, i.e, User notebooks and shared as well. Is there a way to grant this in one statement?

Thanks in advance,
Sasi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a premium instance of Azure Databricks, the below should be what you need.

1. Go to the user's permissions settings.

[image]

2. In the popup, select the user to update their permissions. All users can be selected, as well.

For more details, checkout the [Workspace Access Control doc](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/admin-settings/workspace-acl.html)

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: A Databricks CLI based solution is what I was looking for. Anyways, have taken this as answer.